# what is the unique identifier for twilio message?

Tags: twilio, identifier

Can anyone help with confirming that is there any unique identifier for message?
Is it the "sid", it turns out I have several duplicate records there

Comment: Yes, the `sid` of the message resource is the unique identifier of a message. Can you please explain what you mean with "duplicate records"? Is it possible that you look at another sid here (e.g. the `messagingServiceSID`).

You can find all the properties of the resource listed on the [documentation pages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource).

Comment: thanks for quick response, IOber. I used: 
items = [
               item.date_created, item.to, item.sid, item.status, item.body
                for item in client.messages.list(date_sent_after=start_date, date_sent_before=end_date)]; 
the I found some duplication. @IObert

Comment: I referred this page: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-python

Comment: @IObert  From here https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#instance-properties ; I used the "sid" as the unique identified, then I got several duplication message data for May. The duplications have the same date_created, sid, status, to, body which are columns I want.

Comment: Is it possible that these are duplicates of a message resource object or are you seeing different messages with different time stamps that have the same SID?

Comment: Hi IObert, it's exactly the same message with same time stamp, same sid.

Comment: Mhh weird. Is it possible that you're duplicating some items in this list with the logic? If not, I'd suggest to reach out to support and ask them what is going on there.